# Stuck in Turtle Rock

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

> [image: Link To The Past Level 7 map]
>
> 1. I'm keeping this room for later. All it contains is a full potion of magic.
> 2. "2" marks the spot for a couple of chests. This room and the one next to it are made by a bunch of "bubbles" connected by a pipe system I drew in black.
>
> Note. I escaped the left half of 1F E4 through the magic mirror, as I couldn't find any other way out.
>
> **Errata corrige**: point 2 is in the middle of B1F C3, not C4 as I have mistakenly drawn.

I don't have any key. I imagine 2 holds the big key, but without a key to open that yellow passage I can't get there. I checked every room at least twice. Where did I miss out?

Comment: oof, turtle rock was a pain...first i'd recommend having a mana potion or 2 for when you get lost, and then just make sure to check every room along the way, and every combination of pipe entry (also i believe there was a key under a skull in the first big room)

Comment: @espais Yes, I used it to unlock access to the left half of 1F C4.

Comment: "mana"!? It's magic! Magic meter, medicine of magic, half magic, magic potions! We didn't *have* mana back in that day! Except maybe @Mana. I think Mana was around in those days.

Comment: @Grace There also _is_ a fairy in there...

Comment: Also, by the way, do you know the Ice Rod trick for regaining magic? It'll be a lot nicer on your pocket than having to invest in Medicine of Magic, however free that is anyway.

Comment: oh god grace, you're right.  pickup a **magic** potion or two!

Comment: @Grace Nope, I don't. (Time isn't free. The closest potion store is some quarter hour away.)

Comment: @badp Why not ask about strategies for keeping yourself from running out of magic, then? ♪

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't seem to recall the location of all the keys, so here's a link to a wiki with a map...[Turtle Rock](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_A_Link_to_the_Past/Turtle_Rock#Turtle_Rock)

Answer (score 2):

The key is dropped once I killed the one <s>of those annoying jumpy things</s> Hokuboku in B1F, C2. This unlocks the door to the pipe bringing you to the big key.

Comment: This reminds me of when my roommate (also on the first time playing the game) skipped a certain basic key in the Ice Palace. He combed the *entire* dungeon some 5 times, but skipped the one pot every single time. Glad you got it, though!

Comment: @Grace Yeah, I saw the room, got annoyed by the flying red x's, saw at the bottom a locked door and say "oh well, I'll get through this rigmarole when I'll have the key" and kind of forgot about it.

Comment: @GraceNote I did that in the Water Temple in Ocarina of Time - missed a chest after fighting Shadow Link.